# Can't get Laravel relationship to work

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I dont know what I'm doing wrong today, I can't get a 1-N relationship to work in Laravel 4. I'm trying to describe soccer teams that have many players.

I have a "players.team_id" field. I double-checked the database, the datas are OK.

First model :

```
class Team extends Eloquent {
    public function players() {
        return $this->hasMany('Player');
    }
}
```

Second model :

```
class Player extends Eloquent {
    function team() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Team');
    }
}
```

In my controllers, I can use $player->team but $team->players always retunrs null.

If I try to var_dump $team->players() (I should see the relationship description), it returns an error :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::players()
```

This is what my controller looks like :

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function showTeam($slug) {
        $team = Team::where('slug','=',$slug)->first();

        // this works fine
        $player = Player::find(1);
        var_dump($player->team);

         // this works, too.
         $players = Player::where('team_id','=',516)->get();
         var_dump($players);

         $team = Team::where('slug','=',$slug)->first();
         var_dump($team->players);  // returns null
         var_dump($team->players()); // throws an error

        return View::make('team')
            ->with('team', $team);
    }
}
```

Any leads ? Thank you very much !

Comment: You need to use `hasMany` not `belongsToMany`

Comment: That's what I actually am using, I updated the question.

Comment: Show us your controller code.

Comment: Maybe Laravel just didn't pick up on some changes, try running `php artisan optimize` and `composer dump-auto` just to make sure everything is flushed.

Comment: Try changing `Team::where('slug','=',$slug)->first()` to `Team::with('players')->where('slug','=',$slug)->first()`

Comment: @Quasdunk : composer told me that I had a duplicate in a class name, causing the issue. The model loaded was not the good one. Thanks to both of you !

Comment: You're welcome, glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug thanks to Quasdunk comment.

```
composer dump-auto
```

told me that I had twice the "Team" class.

```
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution
```

I copy/pasted a model file and forgot to change the class name in it. The problem was solved after I renamed this class.